# How to apply "filter" based on regular expression?

Tags: regex, clojure

Is it possible to apply filter based on a regular expression? What I had in mind was something like

```
(filter #"<+\p{Alnum}+>" ["abc" "<def>"])
```

to return

```
=> ["<def>"]
```

Thanks in advance for hints.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Put your regex inside an anonymous function that tests matching to your regex.  The general form would be:

```
(filter #(re-matches REGEX %) SEQUENCE)
```

Where REGEX is the regex that you're interested in, and SEQUENCE is the sequence that you're interested in.  Trying your example,

```
user> (filter #(re-matches #"<+\p{Alnum}+>" %) ["abc" "<def>"])

("<def>")
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't know of `re-matches`.